# User record Vs Solution record

Tags: import

With Import Wizard we can import up to 50,000 records at a time. Now what is the difference between user record and solution record and Does Import Wizard applicable for both ?

Answer (score 1):

Data Import Wizard used for many standard Salesforce objects, including accounts, contacts, leads, **solutions**, and person accounts.

You can not import User records using Import Wizard. You can insert User records using a [Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000007571&language=en_US)

You can import up to 50,000 records at a time using Import Wizard.